# IOError when writing to file in Python

Tags: python, file, file-io

When I try to execute below for writing to file, I get an error as shown below... What am I doing wrong?

```
# create a method that writes to a file.

f = open("C:\Users\QamarAli\Documents\afaq's stuff\myFile.txt", "r+")
f.write('0123456789abcdef')
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r+') or filename: "C:\\Users\\QamarAli\\Documents\x07faq's stuff\\myFile.txt"
>>>
```

Comment: You could also just use forward slashes.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `os.path` and `os.sep` to constructs file paths on windows:

```
import os

file_path = os.path.join("C:" + os.sep, "Users", "QamarAli", "Documents", "afaq's stuff", "myFile.txt")
print file_path
print os.path.exists(file_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

`\a` is an escape sequence (look what happens to it in your filename). Use [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) when working with Windows paths to tell Python not to interpret backslash escape sequences:

```
r"C:\Users\QamarAli\Documents\afaq's stuff\myFile.txt"
^ add this thing
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\\Users\\QamarAli\\Documents\\afaq's stuff\\myFile.txt"

Comment: @AfaqQamar: Does that file exist? No spelling errors in your path?

Comment: no there is no error issues, i pasted it from file properties.

Comment: @AfaqQamar: Does that file exist or are you trying to create it?

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("C:\Users\QamarAli\Documents\afaq's stuff\myFile.txt", "a+")
f.write('0123456789abcdef')
```

instead try this:

```
import os
f = open(os.path.join("C:\\", "Users", "QamarAli", "Documents", "afaq's stuff", "myFile.txt"),  "r+")
f.write('0123456789abcdef')
f.close()
```

make sure the file already exists, and the path is valid.

Also I saw this right now, it seems you may be using the wrong path, look at the error the ineterpreter gave you. Instead of `afaq's stuff` it says `x07faq's stuff` plus it is the only place where I see a single slash. I think I agree with blender that you file path is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Use forward slash in path.

```
f = open("C:/Users/QamarAli/Documents/afaq's stuff/myFile.txt", "r+")
f.write('0123456789abcdef')
```