# Buildbot master's http.log error

Tags: twisted, buildbot

Recently when I tried to restart my buildmaster it failed because of some issues with http.log. I get the following error:

```
2014-07-17 11:21:55+0200 [-] RotateLogSite starting on 8000
2014-07-17 11:21:55+0200 [-] Starting factory <buildbot.status.web.baseweb.RotateLogSite instance at 0x0295F300>
2014-07-17 11:21:55+0200 [-] Setting up http.log rotating 10 files of 10000000 bytes each
2014-07-17 11:21:55+0200 [-] while starting BuildMaster
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\application\service.py", line 308, in addService
        service.privilegedStartService()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\application\service.py", line 277, in privilegedStartService
        service.privilegedStartService()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\application\internet.py", line 358, in privilegedStartService
        self._waitingForPort = self.endpoint.listen(self.factory)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 461, in listen
        interface=self._interface)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 108, in execute
        result = callable(*args, **kw)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 482, in listenTCP
        p.startListening()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 998, in startListening
        self.factory.doStart()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\protocol.py", line 72, in doStart
        self.startFactory()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 1844, in startFactory
        self.logFile = self._openLogFile(self.logPath)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\buildbot-0.8.8-py2.7.egg\buildbot\status\web\baseweb.py", line 477, in _openLogFile
        return LogFile.fromFullPath(path, rotateLength=rotateLength, maxRotatedFiles=maxRotatedFiles)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\logfile.py", line 48, in fromFullPath
        os.path.dirname(logPath), *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\logfile.py", line 161, in __init__
        BaseLogFile.__init__(self, name, directory, defaultMode)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\logfile.py", line 40, in __init__
        self._openFile()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\logfile.py", line 166, in _openFile
        BaseLogFile._openFile(self)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\logfile.py", line 64, in _openFile
        self._file = file(self.path, "r+", 1)
    exceptions.IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r+') or filename: 'E:\\master_dir\\http.log'
```

I found that my http.log has reached a size of 4GB although it should rotate after 10MB. Why the buildbot was not able to rotate the http.log after 10MB? Why I am getting the error `Invalid mode (r+)`? Is there a build config parameter to set the rotate size for `http.log`?

Deleting the file atleast solved the problem of starting buildmaster but I am still clueless why I got this error at the very first place.

I am running buildbot version 0.8.8
Thanks.

**EDIT**

As asked by `djmitche`, I tried with `twisted` logging module. It was logging fine, irrespective of the order of slashes.

```
######## TWISTED ##########
from twisted.python.logfile import LogFile

LOG_FILENAME_TWISTED = r'C:\wp\log_rotate_twisted.log'

lf = LogFile.fromFullPath(LOG_FILENAME_TWISTED, rotateLength=20)

# Log some messages
for i in range(20):
    lf.write('i = %d' % i)
```

Comment: Probably you should write to the buildbot mailing list, there isn't much support in here

Comment: Yeap tats true !! Thanks anyways.

Comment: The Twisted example isn't the same as what Buildbot does - Buildbot uses `LogFile.fromFullPath`.  Try making your example closer to what Buildbot does (see baseweb.py).

The `logging` example is irrelevant, so you could just leave it off.

Comment: @djmitche Updated. Even `LogFile.fromFullPath` behaves the same, logs correctly irrespective of the order of slashes.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, then.  If giving the same inputs to Twisted produces different results in the two different applications, then there's some hidden variable that's not visible in this thread.  Figure out what that is, and you should have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with Twisted Python (and I've proposed adding the corresponding tag).

Can you verify that the log rotation parameters are set correctly, perhaps by patching      `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\buildbot-0.8.8-py2.7.egg\buildbot\status\web\baseweb.py` in _openLogFile to print `rotateLength`?  The printed output will appear in `twistd.log` when you restart the master.

Comment: Yes maybe it is a problem with Twisted.
I tried as you suggested and it says 10000000 bytes (10MB), same as the log msg in the question. 

I just noticed that the both `http.log` and `twisted.log` exceeded 10MB and are currently 250+MB

Comment: What version of Twisted are you using?

Comment: I am using version 13.1.0

Comment: That's fairly new, then.  So, maybe this exception you're seeing on startup is related.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015857/ioerror-when-writing-to-file-in-python suggests that the issue is passing backslashed paths, while Python expects forward-slashed (and converts automatically on Windows).  Try setting your master basedir to `C:/master` instead?

Comment: I quickly checked by writing a small program using `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler` and no matter whether I use forward or backward slashes with the log filename, result stays the same - both ways logfiles rotates and new files are created. So this does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler` is a different piece of code that's not being used in your question, so it doesn't prove much.  Can you try switching the slashes around in your Buildbot config, or possibly construct a test case using `twisted.python.logfile.LogFile`?

Comment: I constructed a test using `twisted.python.logfile.LogFile` and it works correctly - rotates the file after reaching the configured rotating length. Also I switched the slashes but to no avail.